# Google Cloud - Unable to authenticate user with phone number using rest APIs

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to authenticate a user with phone number using Rest APIs and following the documentation given below.

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/TopLevel/getRecaptchaParams
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/sendVerificationCode
https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v1/accounts/signInWithPhoneNumber

Just to let you know, in the cloud console under the same project Identity Platform and other required APIs are enabled.

**Curl Request to generate reCaptcha token:**

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/recaptchaParams?key=[API_KEY]' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "kind": "identitytoolkit#GetRecaptchaParamResponse",
    "recaptchaStoken": "zB06Pvo-22dUOWZiimFpRDUG5Dd9P5Be6IJIjz2xna9cmr-tnD1l-uhVvT5SYj6T5LsDFBUbkHetPv-fG5zF6VLxjl15LuGMuFr1170PhDo",
    "recaptchaSiteKey": "6LcMZR0UAAAAALgPMcgHwga7gY5p8QMg1Hj-bmUv"
}
```

**Curl Request to send verification code to a given number:**

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendVerificationCode?key=[API_KEY]' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw '{
  "phoneNumber": "+923446800107",
  "recaptchaToken": "6LcMZR0UAAAAALgPMcgHwga7gY5p8QMg1Hj-bmUv"
}'
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "CAPTCHA_CHECK_FAILED : Recaptcha verification failed - MALFORMED",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "CAPTCHA_CHECK_FAILED : Recaptcha verification failed - MALFORMED",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using "recaptchaSiteKey" fields value from the response of reCaptcha request as "recaptchaToken" in the send verification code API request as per the document but I am getting the error "CAPTCHA_CHECK_FAILED : Recaptcha verification failed - MALFORMED".

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue or let me know where I am doing incorrect?

As I mentioned earlier, I have enabled all required APIs in google cloud like identity platform, identity toolkit. Also, enabled phone authentication in providers list.

I am using same API KEY got from google cloud project credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReCaptcha requires that you take that site key and plug it into a webpage that runs to validate that the user is not a robot. That site key you would want to stick into the data-sitekey property in the recaptcha page you generate. ReCaptcha, SafteyNet, and iOS attestation providers do not allow you to make requests on-behalf of users without the user providing some sort of attestation confirmation. [This is a really great example](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) of how to set this up. The short of it would look like this:

**HTML Page**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Simple page</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example3"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScipt Page**

```js
var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        alert(response);
      };

grecaptcha.render('example3', {
          'sitekey' : 'your-site-key-from-recaptcha-json-response',
          'callback' : verifyCallback,
          'theme' : 'dark'
        });
```

So when your user presses the reCaptcha for attestation, they are then verified as not being a robot and then they get a key which they can submit to your service. Just remember that you cannot arbitrarily run the reCaptcha from any site or page, it will need to be a page verified in the Firebase Console in the [authentication tab](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/settings) under authorized domains.

Comment: When I add the number I am trying to verify as a test number the response is successful, my question is what happens with real phone numbers coz if the number is not part of the test numbers then the request fails with the error described in this question.